# Update field with Django ORM based on computed value

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a basic model:

```py
class MyModel(Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    is_admin = models.BooleanField()
```

What I want to achieve is to update the value of the `is_admin` field for the entire table at once, based on whether or not the `id` value is in a certain list of values.

Basically, in raw SQL, this is the query I want:

```sql
UPDATE my_model
SET is_admin = (id IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

**How can I achieve this with Django's ORM?**

This is what I tried so far:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Value


admin_ids = (1, 2, 3, 4)

MyModel.objects.update(is_admin=F("id") in admin_ids)
# Resulting query is:
# UPDATE my_model SET is_admin = false

MyModel.objects.update(is_admin=F("id") in Value(admin_ids))
# TypeError: argument of type 'Value' is not iterable

MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=admin_ids).update(admin=True)
MyModel.objects.exclude(id__in=admin_ids).update(admin=False)
# it works... but can I do this in a single query instead of two?
```

I'm using Django 3.2 and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE / WHEN` construction.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/

```
MyModel.objects.update(
    is_admin=Case(
        When(id__in=admin_ids, then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False)
    )
)
```

P.S. If you need this kind of queries a lot, you can use the following custom expression (also useful for annotations). Though be careful, I've had it break once for one query, maybe due to the old version of Django used. On other projects, I am using this in production without any issues.

```
class BooleanQ(ExpressionWrapper):
    output_field = BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        expression = models.Q(*args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(expression, output_field=None)

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        try:
            return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)
        except EmptyResultSet:
            return compiler.compile(Value(False))


MyModel.objects.update(is_admin=BooleanQ(id__in=admin_ids))
```

Comment: It works perfectly :) I'll leave this post open for a bit longer in case a "prettier" approach is suggested, but thanks a lot for your help!